# ngRx : differences between keys from state interface and keys from StoreModule.forRoot

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have just started ngRx and I am facing a small issue.

I would like to know the difference between the keys of both interface states and modules `forRoot`.

```js
export interface ConfigurationState {
  readonly configuration: Configuration;
}
```

```js
StoreModule.forRoot({
  configuration: ConfigurationReducer,
}),
```

```js
export function configurationReducer(state: Configuration = undefined, action: ConfigurationActions.Actions): Configuration {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ConfigurationActions.SET:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```js
this.store.select('configuration')
```

When I select a store with the 4th piece of code, I see an intellisense help for the keys of the 1st piece of code.

If I change the key of the 2nd piece of code, it doesn't change anything.

So my question is, what is the purpose of `forRoot` ? Are the keys important ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inerface's job is typechecking and a bit of intellisense. The `forRoot` is to register your reducers, this is the most important part otherwise your reducers won't get invoked.

In the example you post the `State` interface isn't really adding any value, but if you do it as follows, it adds some typechecking value.

```
// reducer.ts

/**
 * As mentioned, we treat each reducer like a table in a database. This means
 * our top level state interface is just a map of keys to inner state types.
 */
export interface State {
  layout: fromLayout.State;
  router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState;
}

/**
 * Our state is composed of a map of action reducer functions.
 * These reducer functions are called with each dispatched action
 * and the current or initial state and return a new immutable state.
 */
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  layout: fromLayout.reducer,
  router: fromRouter.routerReducer,
};


// app.module.ts
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
```

Taken from the [NgRx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/reducers/index.ts)

Comment: Okay so by using the `ActionReducerMap`, you force your reducers to comply with your interface. Smart ! I indeed didn't go that deep into Ngrx repo, I followed tutorials found all over the internet. Thank you for that piece of code, now I can see why it wasn't working with different keys.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :)